# Left join ON not null columns can't select not null column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Each table has a column RECNUM. They are (decimal(28,0), not null). That is where I am doing my join. I want to select the column DESC in CAUNIT. It is (varchar(28,0), not null). When I run my query I get:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'. Below is my query:

```
SELECT CDCLSVC.UNIT_ID,CAUNIT.DESC
FROM CDCLSVC
LEFT JOIN CAUNIT
ON CDCLSVC.RECNUM = CAUNIT.RECNUM
```

Comment: `SELECT CDCLSVC.UNIT_ID,CAUNIT.[DESC] ...` **`DESC`** is keyword. Quote it with `[]` or rename e.g. "description".

Comment: And try to avoid using SQl server keywords for object names in the future.

Comment: Hi @lad2025: This is not a comment, but the answer :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, but I think that this question is obvious "typo" and should be closed.

Comment: @lad2025: Obviously Chris didn't know that he was using a reserved word when he chose `DESC` for a column name. So this question is okay. And, who knows, someone may even do a similar mistake in the future and be glad to find this request and answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `DESC` column. In `SQL Server` it is a [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx):

> Microsoft SQL Server uses reserved keywords for defining,
>   manipulating, and accessing databases. Reserved keywords are part of
>   the grammar of the Transact-SQL language that is used by SQL Server to
>   parse and understand Transact-SQL statements and batches. **Although it
>   is syntactically possible to use SQL Server reserved keywords as
>   identifiers and object names in Transact-SQL scripts, you can do this
>   only by using delimited identifiers.**

Possible solution:

1. Rename column e.g. `description`
2. Quote it with `[]`

You could also use aliases to avoid typing full table names:

```
SELECT cd.UNIT_ID,ca.[DESC]
FROM CDCLSVC cd 
LEFT JOIN CAUNIT ca
ON cd.RECNUM = ca.RECNUM
```